# Daily Data into Monthly Data Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on an excel project where I have an excel sheet with daily percentage yield data for everyday for 20y. I'm only interested in having the yield of the first entry of each month. How can I accomplish this using excel?

I'm fairly new to excel, any detailed help is truly appreciated.

tl:dr somehow turning daily data to monthly(first occurrence of each month)

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your date is in column A and the yield data in B. Now call column C "Is first day?" and enter this formula into C2:

```
=DAY(A2)=1
```

Or to skip weekends (i.e. first workday of the month)

```
=DAY(A2)=DAY(WORKDAY(EOMONTH(A2,-1),1))
```

Or a more fool proof option (in case of missed days/data points)

```
=MONTH(A3)<>MONTH(A2)          ...start from C3 (make C2 = TRUE)
```

This will literally take the first data point for which the month has changed (compared to the row above it).

Double click the very bottom right corner of cell C2 (the mouse cursor will change into a plus sign before you click). This will auto-fill the formula down, alongside all your data (as long as there is no blank columns between the formula column and your data).

Now select your whole header row, click Home > Sort & Filter > Filter. You should see little arrows appear next to each column header. Click the arrow next to "Is first day?" and uncheck "FALSE". Now all non-first occurrences of the month will be hidden. You can copy and paste this data to a new sheet if required. To see all the data again click Home > Sort & Filter > Clear.

Comment: If this worked for you, please do checkmark the answer so others may know a solution has been found.

Comment: This worked wonderfully. However, since the data only reports weekdays, the first occurrence of a specific month sometimes is the 2nd or even 3rd. Is there some way to account for this as well?

Comment: Further, when I try to select and copy all the cells, it only pastes some of the selection which seems odd.

Comment: @somnaik09 update solution for weekends. Note you can also add your national holidays and leave to the WORKDAY function e.g. `WORKDAY(EOMONTH(A2,-1),1,{"2021/01/01","2021/12/01"})` will skip new years and say 1 Dec because say you took leave.

Comment: @somnaik09 As for the copy-and-paste issue, after you filtered for all "Is first day?" = TRUE, select any cell in your table and hit CTRL+A to select all. Now copy and paste to a new sheet. Everything should be there.

Answer (score 0):

*To yield the first entry of each month, follow below shown method:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Array (CSE) Formula in cell O58:

  `{=MIN(IF(TEXT($K$58:$K$73,"MMMM")=$N58,$K$58:$K$73))}`
- Formula in cell P58:
  `=IFERROR(INDEX($L$58:$L$73,MATCH($O58,$K$58:$K$73,0)),"")`

**N.B.**

- *If you want to skip Helper data in column O, then you may use this array (CSE) formula:*

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($L$58:$L$73,MATCH(MIN(IF(TEXT($K$58:$K$73,"MMMM")=$N58,$K$58:$K$73)),$K$58:$K$73,0)),"")}
  ```

*Finish array formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.*

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*